# Get the new square InfoWindows with Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm building a website that's primarily function is a map search and displays professional wrestling events happening across the UK. I'm using v3 of the Google Maps JavaScript API to achieve this, but I have a question about why my app's InfoWindows look different to the InfoWindows on [maps.google.co.uk](http://maps.google.co.uk/).

Compare the following two screen-shots. Mine:

[image]

And the Google Maps website:

[image]

Why does the Google Maps website have squared InfoWindows, and why does my app using the latest version of the Google Maps JavaScript API have rounded InfoWindows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Martin,

I've gone to the Google Maps API demos and found this demo:

http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geocoder/v3-geocoder-tool.html#q%3D42.032974%2C-90.703125

You should see the squared InfoWindow.

I looked under the hood and found the code below, could be the bounds overlay of your window. Hope it helps.

```
var openInfoWindow = function(resultNum, result, marker) {
    return function() {
      if (selected != null) {
        document.getElementById('p' + selected).style.backgroundColor = "white";
        clearBoundsOverlays();
      }

      map.fitBounds(result.geometry.viewport);
      infowindow.setContent(getAddressComponentsHtml(result.address_components));
      infowindow.open(map, marker);

      if (result.geometry.bounds) {
        boundsOverlay = new google.maps.Rectangle({
          'bounds': result.geometry.bounds,
          'strokeColor': '#ff0000',
          'strokeOpacity': 1.0,
          'strokeWeight': 2.0,
          'fillOpacity': 0.0
        });
        boundsOverlay.setMap(map);
        google.maps.event.addListener(boundsOverlay, 'click', onClickCallback);
        document.getElementById('boundsLegend').style.display = 'block';
      } else {
        boundsOverlay = null;
      }

      viewportOverlay = new google.maps.Rectangle({
          'bounds': result.geometry.viewport,
          'strokeColor': '#0000ff',
          'strokeOpacity': 1.0,
          'strokeWeight': 2.0,
          'fillOpacity': 0.0
        });
      viewportOverlay.setMap(map);
      google.maps.event.addListener(viewportOverlay, 'click', onClickCallback);
      document.getElementById('viewportLegend').style.display = 'block';

      document.getElementById('p' + resultNum).style.backgroundColor = "#eeeeff";
      document.getElementById('matches').scrollTop =
        document.getElementById('p' + resultNum).offsetTop -
        document.getElementById('matches').offsetTop;
      selected = resultNum;
    }
  }
```

Comment: It seems, for some reason, when you specify the `size` option when initialising the infowindow. Strange!

Answer (score 1):

Just a small note. It seams that v2 of the API now has the squared info windows. I have the same question. But maybe it will be fixed automatically on v3 soon as well.

Comment: It's strange: ever since I specified the `size` parameter when initialising an `InfoWindow` they've been the square version as on Google Maps. Even now, where I've removed that declaration. I wonder if something was cached, or if I did something to 'enable' the pretty new infowindow design?